# Executing R script with Python via subprocess.call

Tags: python, r

I have a R script which works fine on its own but I need it to be a part of python script. So, when I run the python script the R script be executed automatically.
I use the below command; there is no error but the R script output files are not created.

```
import subprocess

retcode = subprocess.call("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/bin/Rscript --vanilla T:/2012.R", shell=True)
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I try it, but still no result with no error message.

Comment: What happens with a simple test program: `print.hw <- function() {
    print("hello world")
}; 
print.hw()`

Comment: Is there a syntax error with the path to the Rscript interpreter? My intuition is that you need to escape any space characters in the path.

C:/Program\ Files/R/R-3.2.2/bin/Rscript

Comment: Does exact command run in Command Prompt or PowerShell: `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/bin/Rscript --vanilla T:/2012.R`?

Comment: @42 the test program works fine.

Comment: Then you need to produce the code of 2012.R.

Comment: @42 @ Parfait First problem was with "RODBC" library in R which I solved it. Now, when I copy and past my code in "command Prompt" it works, but it does not work in python shell. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Code.. code..code. Stop wasting our time vague error descriptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply place your string command in brackets and break string into separate components as the first parameter of function expects a list of arguments, per the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

> subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
>   shell=False)

```
import subprocess

retcode = subprocess.call(['C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/bin/Rscript', '--vanilla', 
                           'T:/2012.R'], shell=True)
```

Alternatively, break it up into multiple strings:

```
command = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/bin/Rscript'
arg = '--vanilla'
path2script = 'T:/2012.R'

retcode = subprocess.call([command, arg, path2script], shell=True)
```