# how to correctly get R sessionInfo() from python by using system call on windows?

Tags: python, r, subprocess

I want to print out the current R session info in python script by using `subprocess.call()`. I am new to use of `subprocess.call()`, I looked into several [`SO` post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760210/executing-r-script-with-python-via-subprocess-call) to access R script from python, so I tried the same way, but I couldn't print out current R session info correctly. I am using windows, and I am opening jupyter notebook from termianl. Here is what I tried:

**my attempt**:

I simply want to access some R built-in function (some baseR functions, such as `sessionInfo()`) from python:

```
import subprocess

command = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/bin/Rscript'
arg = '--vanilla'
funcs = 'sessionInfo()'

retcode = subprocess.call([command, arg, funcs], shell=True)
```

but this can't print out R session info correctly, what I got is `0` or `1`. I think my way of calling R built-in function from python is not correct. can anyone show me a workable solution to make this happen? what's wrong with my attempt? how can I get current R session info() from python script? how can I access R built-in functions from python? any thought? thanks

Comment: btw `0` and `1` are the result of `subprocess.call`. Typically, `0` means success, anything besides `0` means some sort of failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
# Python 3.7.6 (default, Dec 30 2019, 19:38:28) 
# [Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)] on darwin

import subprocess

subprocess.call([
  'Rscript',
  '--vanilla',
  '-e',
  'sessionInfo()'
])
```

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0
```

Comment: what `Rscript` refers to? is it path like: `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3\bin\x64\Rscript` in my machine? can you add few more detailed steps how to set this right? where do I call `subprocess.call()`, in terminal, or jupter notebook, like python `xx.py`? I plant to call `xx.py` file.

Comment: you'll need to work out the PATH stuff separately... you referred to a C:/ path in your original post, hopefully it's as simple as replacing Rscript with the full path

Comment: it worked. so what's the problem of my first attempt? want to learn my mistake from it.

Comment: As near as I can tell you're just missing `-e`. IINM without that `sessionInfo()` is interpreted as a filename. I'm not as familiar with windows but IIRC you should be able to open up a windows shell and run `C:\\path\to\Rscript -e "sessionInfo()"` -- `subprocess.call` is just imitating that. So I might try to get it working in the terminal first. See `?Rscript` in R and/or `Rscript --help` in the terminal